# Undefined reference with clang++ with O2

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++, libc++

I'm trying CLang 3.4 and libc++ on a project and I get strange linking errors in release mode:

```
/home/wichtounet/dev/eddic/src/ast/Operator.cpp:17: error: undefined reference to
'std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&
 std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>(
   std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&,
   std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&
 )'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Everything compiles fine. The program links correctly in debug mode, but doesn't when I use O2. In O0, O1 and Os everything works fine, but it doesn't links in O2, O3, Os. I also tried in LTO mode and it works fine.

I tried two versions of libc++ but to no avail.

The code does not seems bad to me:

```
std::ostream& ast::operator<< (std::ostream& stream, ast::Operator op){
    std::string value = "asd";
    return stream << value;
}
```

but I haven't a simple example causing the problem.

clang++ is used to both build and links the code. I used "-std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++" to compile and the same plus some library stuff to link.

What could possibly cause that ?

EDIT: Full invocation of link step in release mode:

```
clang++ -v -use-gold -Iinclude -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -Wextra -Wall -Qunused-arguments -Wuninitialized -Wsometimes-uninitialized -Wno-long-long -Winit-self -Wdocumentation -pedantic -isystem /home/wichtounet/build/modular-boost//include -L /home/wichtounet/build/modular-boost//lib -lboost_program_options -g -DLOGGING_DISABLE -DNDEBUG -O3 -march=native -fvectorize -fslp-vectorize-aggressive -fomit-frame-pointer -o release/bin/eddic "TONS OF DOT O"
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2
 "/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o release/bin/eddic /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtbegin.o -L/home/wichtounet/build/modular-boost//lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../.. -L/lib -L/usr/lib -lboost_program_options "TONS OF DOT O" -lc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
src/ast/Operator.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I can imagine system headers altering what other system headers they include on the basis of debug vs. release build. Did you `#include <string>`, or are you relying on some other header that sometimes includes it for you?

Comment: Yes, I include <string> in the file where the problem seems to be.

Comment: Another possibly stupid question: I see the error message says "clang" and not "clang++", if your link command is in fact using "clang" instead of "clang++" it will not include the c++ standard library in the linking process.

Comment: @Casey, failing to `#include <string>` would typically produce a compile-time error, not a link error.  However, using `clang` instead of `clang++` is very likely to give you link problems.

Comment: The link is done with /usr/bin/ld. I tried using llvm-link instead, but it doesn't seem to change. By the way, I'm using CMake by the way.

Comment: That's not what was being asked. The question was if you used "clang" or "clang++". "clang" _compiles_ c++ just fine, but it doesn't link to the standard c++ library like clang++ does. This is the kinda error you get when that happens.

Comment: I'm of course using Clang++. It works perfectly on debug mode. It wouldn't work at all on debug with clang. It is only on release mode (O2 or O3) that it fails.

Comment: I think that `/usr/bin/ld` is wrong.  It won't automatically add the C++ runtime libraries.  Try linking using `clang++` (which is capable of both compiling and linking).  If you use `/usr/bin/ld`, you'll need to add the C++ standard libraries to the link line yourself, and if you're doing that now, perhaps you're only adding the debug version of the libraries (which wouldn't necessarily have the same symbols as the link libraries and may result in linkage problems).

Comment: I'm now linking with clang++ but with no difference. Both compile and link phase are made directly with clang++. It works perfectly in O0 and O1 but from O2 it does not work any more (same with O3 and Ofast).

Comment: Just brainstorming. Should this stuff be able to compile with `-std=c++11`? If so, what happens then at the problem optimization levels?

Comment: You should try the `-v` flag to output the different command lines of compilation and link and compare them between debug and release and look for difference on paths for example.

Comment: @galop1n, @Baptiste Wicht, not only `-v` but also `-save-temps` and compare temporary files.. You may repeat `ld` linker command with `--no-demangle` option added; then you will be able to grep temporary files for the problem function. (ps, please check, do you clean the project between experiments)

Comment: @galop1n I added the -v output. And yes, this stuff should definitely wors with c++11 and the code used to works fine on G++ and on Clang 3.1 (I never tried with libc++ at this time). 
I also tried in LTO mode and it works fine.

Comment: I have noticed that your operator<< is taking an object and not a const reference. Do you have an auto_ptr inside ast::Operator object?

Comment: ast::Operator is a class enum. Moreover, I didn't use the param op in the code.

Comment: What happens when you are explicitly explicitly using the libc++ standard implementation with `-nostdinc++ -Ipath/to/libcxx/include -Lpath/to/libcxx/lib` ?

Comment: After reading all of those comments, I think it's would be helpful that @BaptisteWicht could upload a small set of codes that can reproduce the problem, otherwise everyone is guessing :)

Comment: @Jason I wish I could, but I never was able to isolate it. The "solution" was to inline the function in the header and it worked, but I still don't know the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this problem with code that has long compiled with g++, attempting to compile with clang++. Same symptoms: undefined references to std::__1::basic_ostream<...> that magically went away when -O2 was removed from the compiler options. All similar reports I was finding were about erroneously using clang instead of clang++ to compile C++ code, but that wasn't the case for me: I was using clang++.

I was finally able to determine that the issue (for me) was using `#include <iosfwd>` (which has iostream forward declarations only, to reduce compile times) in my header (.h) file declaring a class but not using `#include <iostream>` in the corresponding source (.cpp) file implementing the class.

Once I added the `#include <iostream>` to the source file and recompiled, these undefined reference errors went away.

Comment: So one TU sees only a template declaration, assumes the instantiation has been done somewhere else and requires it. Another TU has the définition, but only actually emits the function at optimization levels *where the call isn't inlined*. Finally, LTO allows inlining everywhere, hiding the issue again. I think you're spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I notice in the error message "std::__1::operator<<". In the cpp code I see "ast::operator<<". 
This gives the impression that something is going wroing with the namespaces.

Now I don't know if *ast* is a class or a namespace, but in both cases that looks a bit off.

If *ast* is a class, then I'm not sure if the operator<< is allowed as class member. See:
http://www.cs.nctu.edu.tw/cis/chinese/doc/research/c++/C++FAQ-English/input-output.html#faq-15.8. It suggests that the operator<< should be implemented as a friend, not as a member of the class. You could try making it a friend method and see if that resolves the problem.

If *ast* is a namespace, then I would try to remove "asd::", and add seperate namespace declarations around the definition.

Comment: It is a namespace. I tried putting it into global namespace but it didn't change anything.

Comment: libc++ defines all of its functions/classes in an inline namespace inside of `std` named `__1`. This done to allow for future extensions. I don't think the `__1` here is a problem.