# Linker errors when optimization greater than -O1 (clang++)

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I have a moderately large C++ / ObjC++ project in XCode, which compiles/links/runs just fine at -O0 (in Debug config), as well as with -O1, but anywhere above -O1 I get two very strange linker errors:

`"std::__1::vector<BufferBinding, std::__1::allocator<BufferBinding> >::~vector()", referenced from: ... LevelSystem.o`

`"std::__1::vector<TextureHandle, std::__1::allocator<TextureHandle> >::~vector()", referenced from: ... LevelSystem.o`

Oddly, `vector<BufferBinding>` and `vector<TextureHandle>` are used in many places in different object files, but I am only getting linker errors for my 'LevelSystem.cpp'.  FWIW, LevelSystem.o is included via a separately compiled static library...

Unfortunately I have not been able to come up with a small code snippet to reproduce this problem, so rather then expecting a concrete solution I was just hoping for any advice for possible places to look or steps to debug further.

Compiling with 
clang++ -x objective-c++ -arch arm64 -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -O2  (...)

I know this is very little to go on, but Im just posting here in case anyone has experienced this kind of thing in the past and can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

EDIT:

TextureHandle is a pimpl-y class, so really contains nothing more then a pointer to a forward-declared struct.

BufferBinding contains only an `id<MTLBuffer>` (and a few ints) which is ARCed, which is suspicious, but then again TextureHandle exhibits the same problem without having any ObjC pointers...

Comment: Have you looked at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22972545/10077)?

Comment: I have, thank you.  I haven't seen any signs of a missing include, or lonely forward declarations for any of these objects (especially not std::vector)...  I will keep searching though, it does seem like the potential culprit.